# java.lang.ClassNotFoundException [JavaFx - ObjectProperty]

Tags: java, web-services, javafx, object-property

I set a WebService on tomcat on aws Server.

The code throws an exception:

```
23-Jan-2015 08:44:07.941 SEVERE [http-nio-8080-exec-4] null.null javafx/beans/property/ObjectProperty
 java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: javafx/beans/property/ObjectProperty
    at scrabble.webService.ScrabbleGame.<init>(ScrabbleGame.java:72)
    at scrabble.webService.ScrabbleWS.createScrabbleGame(ScrabbleWS.java:151)
    at scrabble.webService.ScrabbleWS.createGame(ScrabbleWS.java:84)
```

The client invokes constructor to create new Game:

```
public final class GameManager {


private Board board;
private LettersBank bank;
private String gameName;

private Player[] players;
private final ArrayList<String> resignedPlayers;
private int currentPlayerIndex = 0;

final private ObjectProperty<Player> currentPlayerProperty; <<<<

final private BooleanProperty gameFinishedProperty;
private boolean isLastRound = false;
private boolean isEndGame = false;

public GameManager() {
    this.computerFinishedPlayingProperty = new SimpleBooleanProperty();
    this.gameFinishedProperty = new SimpleBooleanProperty(false);
    this.currentPlayerProperty = new SimpleObjectProperty<Player>();
    this.board = null;
    this.gameName = "";
    this.resignedPlayers = new ArrayList<String>();
    this.bank = new LettersBank();
    computerFinishedPlayingProperty.set(false);
}
```

I think line with **<<<<** is the problem.

Comment: What have you written in `ScrabbleGame.java` line :72?

Comment: gameEngine = new GameManager();

Comment: What is the java version running on the `aws server`?

Comment: You are right, it's java 6.
How can I make a tomcat server with Java 8 on aws?

Comment: Are you using AWS EC2 Linux?

Comment: I used AWS Elastic Beanstalk to set tomcat Server using Java 8 , but NetBeans installs it only as Java 6

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/69435/discussion-between-arie-and-itachiuchiha).